# How can I run python script from Google Apps Script?

Tags: python, github, google-apps-script

I want to run a python script from Google Apps Script automatically. I have used this code, but as the script is in python, it does not execute:

```
function runPythonScript() {
  var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anemartinez1/tuduu/main/src/prueba2.py';

  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'contentType': 'application/json'
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var content = response.getContentText();

  try {
    eval(content);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log("Error: " + e.message);
  }
}
```

How can I run the python script that is on github?

Comment: Is that Javascript?  Where are you running that Javascript?  You can't run Python code from Javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running python script from Google Apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218932/running-python-script-from-google-apps-script)

Comment: Have you done much research on this, or are you just checking in to see whether there have been any recent changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launching Python script from Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048109/launching-python-script-from-google-apps-script)